# HTML | Horizontal Menu getting out of the block while shrinking the browser size

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title> Playing with Cascading Style Sheets </title>

            <style type = "text/css">

                 .nav {     background-color : green;
                            height : 35px;
                            font-size : 25px;
                            font-weight : bold;
                            display : block;
                      }

                .nav ul {   
                            list-style : none;
                            margin : 0;
                            padding : 0;
                            display : inline;
                        }
                .nav li {
                            display : inline;
                            padding : 100px;
                            vertical-align : middle;
                        }
                .nav a {
                            text-decoration : none;
                            padding : 8px 8px 8px 8px;
                            color : white;
                            vertical-align : middle;
                       }
                .nav a:hover 
                       { 
                        color : black;
                        background-color : white;
                       }
            </style>
       </head>
        <body>


            <div class = "nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "">Links</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>              
        </body>
</html>
```

Query :- While using the background-color style on body tag at the style tag or by another way like using div tag the horizontal menu is not working as it works before without using the background color.

Problem with using background color is that after using it the horizontal menu context get outs of its div block of **class= ".nav"** when I shrink the browser size.

Comment: try this      <div class = "nav" style="display:table">  ,  or display: inline

Comment: How do you want to solve it? Crop it or make it smaller?

Comment: **@Vicmathur**  It is not working...

Comment: Dear @Bálint, Actually the problem is the above code is working fine but when i add a background color and try to resize my browser. The Horizontal menu is not dynamically shrinking with it. It's menu content get out of it green background.

Comment: How could adding a background color changing the scaling of an element

Comment: @Bálint please, try the above code. It will work, if you resize the browser the horizontal menu will also change according to it. After this add a background color then resize your browser the content will come out of its green background.